# django-sphinx battery support python3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-sphinx

I'm trying to install django-sphinx using pip-3.2 but I have syntax error.

Please, tell me how to install django-sphinx with Python 3.2.

i download sphinx deb package from from http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/release/ 
install :

```
dpkg -i sphinxsearch_2.1.4-release-1~wheezy_amd64.deb
```

install log:

```
    Do not forget to reindex all indexes by running: indexer --all

Starting sphinxsearch: Sphinx 2.1.4-id64-release (rel21-r4421)
Copyright (c) 2001-2013, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2013, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
listening on all interfaces, port=9312
listening on all interfaces, port=9306
precaching index 'test1'
WARNING: index 'test1': preload: failed to open /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/test1.sph: No such file or directory; NOT SERVING
precaching index 'test1stemmed'
WARNING: index 'test1stemmed': preload: failed to open /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/test1stemmed.sph: No such file or directory; NOT SERVING
WARNING: multiple addresses found for 'localhost', using the first one (ip=127.0.0.1)
precaching index 'rt'
precached 3 indexes in 0.040 sec
sphinxsearch is started.
```

after install sphinx i run pip-3.2 and try install django-sphinx:
install log:

```
Downloading/unpacking django-sphinx
  Downloading django-sphinx-2.2.4.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package django-sphinx

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distri
bution
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in /usr/local/l
ib/python3.2/dist-packages (from django-sphinx)
Installing collected packages: django-sphinx
  Running setup.py install for django-sphinx

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distri
bution
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/djangosphinx/config.py", line
 56
        print render_to_string(getattr(settings, 'SPHINX_CONFIG_TEMPLATE', 'conf
/sphinx.conf'), context)
                             ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/djangosphinx/apis/current.py"
, line 5
        except ImportError, exc:
                          ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/djangosphinx/apis/api278/__in
it__.py", line 78
        SPH_ATTR_MULTI                  = 0X40000000L
                                                     ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/djangosphinx/apis/api275/__in
it__.py", line 75
        SPH_ATTR_MULTI                  = 0X40000000L
                                                     ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/djangosphinx/apis/api263/__in
it__.py", line 119
        except socket.error, msg:
                           ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/djangosphinx/utils/config.py"
, line 18
        raise ValueError, "Only MySQL and PostgreSQL engines are supported by Sp
hinx."
                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/djangosphinx/models.py", line
 450
        raise NotImplementedError, 'Related object and/or multiple field lookups
not supported'
                                 ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/djangosphinx/management/comma
nds/generate_sphinx_config.py", line 19
        print generate_config_for_model(model, index)
                                      ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Successfully installed django-sphinx
Cleaning up...
```

Maybe my problem  : django -sphinx dont support python3.X ? 
https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/search/

Comment: Adding the error might help.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/FXuqj9G7  install log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reasons you get syntax errors is that `try` / `except` syntax changed from Python 2 to Python 3.

In Python 3 you should use

```
except ImportError as exc:
```

instead of

```
except ImportError, exc:
```

It's not about import syntax only, reading the error messages we see there are other problems due to incompatibilities between the two versions. I guess django-sphinx has not been updated to work with Python 3.

References: http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html